# View not updating in OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, user-interface

i am trying to make an E-Leaning app.
I have a submit button, that when pressed, sends the user's answer to a server to be evaluated.
During that evaluation, I want to display a loading indicator (I am simply using Android Studio's progress bar).

During the onViewCreated of my fragment, I set the onClickListener as follows:

```
submit_button.setOnClickListener {
        submit_button.isClickable = false
        loadingIndicator.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        inputFragment.passDataToActivityAndEvaluate()
    }
```

On press, a coroutine is launched that makes an html request. After that, I want to hide the loading spinner before navigating the child fragment

```
loadingIndicator.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
submit_button.isClickable = true
```

The idea sounded simple enough, however, I discovered that when trying to make any form of UI change in the OnClickListener, it only **gets applied when the evaulation is already done and the app has navigated to the next fragment**.

Comment: Likely your coroutine or something else around `passDataToActivityAndEvaluate()` is blocking the main UI thread

Comment: @laalto Sounds like using activity.runOnUiThread() should prevent that, no? I tried that and it unfortunately did not fix the issue.

Comment: `runOnUiThread()` as the name implies, runs on ui thread (and blocks it).

Comment: I understand. I do the UI adjustments via runOnUiThread() and the http request on the main thread, shouldn't they be able to run independently this way?

Comment: main thread is the UI thread. You need a background thread for background work and to keep the main UI thread available to e.g. update the screen as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the functionality of coroutines and managed to fix it.